# How do I only record certain values to CSV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, file-writing

I am new to python so forgive me if this is a super simple question. I currently have an arduino sending 3 values through the serial port. After this, it is decoded and split. I only want to record a line of values to csv if Value 1 is above 120. Whenever I try this, the code breaks instantly. Thank you.

```py
import serial
import csv


Finger = "1"
ser = serial.Serial('COM6', 9600)

while True:
    try:
        data = ser.readline()
        decode = (data[0:len(data)-2].decode("utf-8"))
        datasplit = decode.split('-')
        Val1 = datasplit [0]
        Val2 = datasplit [1]
        Val3 = datasplit [2]
        print(Val1)
        with open("EMGSig16.csv","a") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",")
            if Val1 >= 120:
                writer.writerow([Finger,Val1,Val2,Val3])
            else:
                continue
    except:
        break
```

Edit: Sorry for the delayed response (I work 3rd shift). Here is a screenshot of my normal values without the threshold
[Normal Value 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8ktx.png). When I add the threshold back in I get this [With Threshold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL8Ag.png).

Comment: You should print or log your error, it might help you and reader. You can do it with `except Exception as e: print(e)`. Maybe, you have an error because `Val1` is not an int and the comparison fail. To convert, do a `int(datasplit[0])`.

Comment: can you please print all the Vals? and then edit the question with output. or print and edit question for the error traceback.

Comment: maybe the datasplit variable stores str type values. please check by typing type(Val1)

Comment: @ndclt I've tried this method with the same results as my previous tries.

Comment: @MadhurYadav Yes! The variables are str type values, but when I used int(datasplit[0]) as suggested above, I still had the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I just randomly deleted the Try and Exception because I thought that might be breaking the code and it worked! No explanation why, but if anyone else has this problem, here is my final code:

```
import serial
import csv


Finger = "1"
ser = serial.Serial('COM6', 9600)

while True:
        data = ser.readline()
        decode = (data[0:len(data)-2].decode("utf-8"))
        datasplit = decode.split('-')
        Val1 = int(datasplit[0])
        Val2 = int(datasplit[1])
        Val3 = int(datasplit[2])
        print(Val1)
        if Val1 >= 100:
            with open("EMGSig17.csv","a") as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",")
                writer.writerow([Finger,Val1,Val2,Val3])
        else:
            continue
```